# How to share state between viewControllers using the AppDelegate object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to share an NSArray object between several different view controllers and my first thought was to add a property on the app delegate as they all have access to this object.

But after some debugging it appears I can't actually share this array for some reason.  When I set the object from the first view controller and NSLog the results all is well.  But when I attempt to get that array value using another view controller object it always returns UITouchData (not the value previously shown in the logs after my first view controller set the value)

Here is the code that I'm using to set the value

```
NSArray* cookies = [NSHTTPCookie 
                    cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] 
                    forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

  [appDelegate setAuthCookie:cookies];
```

Here is part of the .h for my app delegate

```
@interface SomeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  NSArray* authCookie;
}

@property (retain) NSArray* authCookie;

- (void)setAuthCookie:(NSArray *)cookie;
- (NSArray *)getAuthCookie;

@end
```

Here is the .m for the methods in question

```
@synthesize authCookie;

- (void)setAuthCookie:(NSArray *)cookie
{
  authCookie = cookie;  
}

- (NSArray *)getAuthCookie
{
  return authCookie;
}
```

Here is the attempt to grab this array in the second view controller that fails (technically it doesn't fail on this line but I don't get an NSArray back as expected so when I try to use this it fails)

```
NSArray* cookies = [appDelegate getAuthCookie];
```

Any way I can share state using the app delegate like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memory management is wrong, and you are getting a completely different object which has inherited the old array's address when you later use the getter.

Your @property is correct, but you've written your own setter and getter that do not retain the object. You don't need to use both @property/@synthesize and supply your own getter/setter. The former is a newer means of automating the latter.

If you remove your implementations of setAuthCookier: and getAuthCookie then your code should work.

Comment: I actually tried that initially but when I try to set or get from the property directly it always blows up (ie- [appDelegate authCookie:cookies];) - how SHOULD I do this revised get/set you mentioned? the syntax seems to be different than I expected (thanks for the answer btw!)

Comment: Use just @property/@synthesize, but the setter will still be called setAuthCookie:, not authCookie:. The 'set' is implied by normal Objective-C conventions. The getter will then be just [appDelegate authCookie]. Alternatively, use Objective-C dot syntax — 'appDelegate.authCookie = cookies' to set and 'something = appDelegate.authCookie' to get.

Comment: Awesome!  You just saved me what has been a 2 day thrashing session (thank you thank you thank you)!!!